# Save .zip or .rar file from raw data returned by http request

Tags: node.js, zip, httprequest, node-modules, rar

I am trying to save a file (.rar or .zip) from raw data returned by a http request using request-promisse package.

Example of raw data:

```
    PK   ��bM            -   legendas_tv_20181102222115212/Legendas.tv.url%�1�0�@���,d���:U�Lѯ5ޓ�U�oJ����� �[8��V�����V��c�d7Z��Y�VW�>�T��t �\�>#e��W$� ��{(UU���8~�PKq���r   }   PK
```

Example code:

```
    const fs = require('fs');
    const rp = require('request-promise').defaults({jar: true});

    rp.get(options).then(function(res){
            console.log(res.headers);

            ficheiro = res.body;

            //Tried this method and doesn't work either
            //ficheiro = new Buffer(res.body);

            file = fs.writeFile("teste5.zip", ficheiro, function(err) {
                if(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log("The file was saved!");
                }
            });
    })
```

The file is saved on my server but when I try to open it returns this errors:

[image: error]

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regular npm package request (which already uses promises):

```
const fs = require('fs');
const rp = require('request').defaults({jar: true});

rp
.get(url)
.on('response', function(response)
{
    console.log(response.statusCode)
    console.log(response.headers['content-type'])
})
.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('file.zip'));
```